# Declare a dictionary with explicit types node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I'm doing this using node.js:

```
var cart = {}
```

in a for loop I do

```
cart[id] = []
cart[id].push(element)
```

Of course there will be always one element in cart.

I want to do something like:

```
var cart: {'':[]} = {}
```

There's a way to do it in a clever way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class Dictionary extends Map {
   constructor(){
     super();
   }
   add(id, data){
     if(this.has(id)){
       this.get(id).push(data);
     }else{
       this.set(id, [data]);
     }
     return this;
   }
}
```

So one can do:

```
const dictionary = new Dictionary();
dictionary
  .add(1, "el")
  .add(2,"el")
  .add(1,"el2");

console.log(dictionary.get(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an array that contains an element like this:

```
cart[id] = [element];
```